# An equivalent formulation of $X=xx^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove $X=xx^T\Longleftrightarrow \left(
\begin{matrix}
X & x\\
x^T & 1\end{matrix}
\right)\succeq 0$ and $\operatorname{Rank} \left(
\begin{matrix}
X & x\\
x^T & 1\end{matrix}
\right)=1$?

The $\Rightarrow$ part is trivial. However, $\Leftarrow$ part is tough for me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Write $X=xx^T+B$ where $B\succeq0$ and then prove bad things about $B$.

Comment: We're missing some information here.  For instance, if 
$$
X = \pmatrix{2&2\\2&2}
$$
and $x = (1,1)^T$, then the condition on the right holds but $X \neq xx^T$. Are we given, perhaps, that both matrices are of trace $1$?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! You are right. Accordingly, I have modified my question and I guess the new proposition may hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can actually prove that $X=xx^T$ if $A=\pmatrix{X&x\\ x^T&1}$ has rank $1$.

Let $v=\pmatrix{x\\ 1}$. If $A$ has rank $1$, then every row/column of $A$ is a scalar multiple of the last row/column. Hence $A=cvv^T$ for some complex scalar $c$. By comparing the bottom right entries on both sides, one may determine $c$ and express $X$ in terms of $x$.